# How to use a model with a string array in JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, string, angular

I am new to Angular and am currently having trouble with getting my JSON info to work together.

I have temporary JSON data inside my service and it uses a model to define the types of data inside the JSON. My goal is to have a list of properties inside my properties part of my data so that in my code I can check what properties the array contains. However I am not sure how to set my model up correctly.

Here is an example of my data:

```
  {
            "Id": 4,
            "Title": "Global Emerging Markets",
            "Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sollicitudin ornare lectus, quis gravida tortor venenatis nec. ",
            "IUrl": "www.google.com",
            "FUrl": "www.google.com",
            "OUrl": "www.google.com",
            "WUrl": "www.google.com",
            "MUrl": "www.google.com",
            "Properties": ["institutional", "personal"],

  },
```

Here is my model (and yes I know it is probably very wrong):

```
export class Brands {
    Id: number;
    Title: string;
    Description: string;
    IUrl: string;
    FUrl: string;
    OUrl: string;
    WUrl: string;
    MUrl: string;
    Properties: string;
}
```

Currently I am getting the error `"Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'`.

Do you know how I can correct my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its just like that

```
Properties: string[];
```

or

```
Properties: Array<string>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, cannot believe I was so close.

Answer (score 1):

The Error is staightforward when it says:

> "Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

So it tries to store a `string[]` into a `string` in the `Properties` field, but it fails, so that's why you get the Error.

So instead of `string` you should declare `Properties` as `string[]` in your model.